# Row in table which is relation many to many doesnt get a proper id for field

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, entity

I cannot get a ID from InDirect table to my main table. When I created this in one method. This is relation many to many.

```
var reservation = new Reservation()
     foreach (var item in cartItems)
            {
                var paymentInDirect = new PaymentInDirect
                {
                    ReservationID = reservation.ID,
                    Reservation  = reservation,
                    Payment.ID= payment.ID,
                };
                _db.PaymentInDirect.Add(paymentInDirect );

                reservation.PaymentInDirect.Add(paymentInDirect );
                reservation.PaymentInDirectID = paymentInDirect .ID;

            }
reservation.UserID= uzytkownikID;
reservation.DateCreatedReservation = DateTime.Now
_db.Reservation.Add(reservation);
_db.SaveChanges()
```

As you can see below row is from Reservation table and I get a PaymentInDirectID = 0.

ReservationID| PaymentInDirectID| UserID| DateCreated

10 | 0 | 32 | 30-11-2017

And if i want display a proper row from PaymentInDirectID. Then this row has a proper reservation ID to my recently added.